# Routing with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to structure my page so that single product could be accessed via `/products/CATEGORY_ID/SUBCATEGORY_ID/PRODUCT_ID`

The problem is that when I click on the product that has a Link like this: 
`<Link to={'${product.slug}'} className='products__product-link' key={product.id}>`, it changes the `SUBCATEGORY_ID`, not pushes `PRODUCT_ID`. How to fix this problem?

My Routes:

```
      <Route exact path='/products/:id' component={Products} />
      <Route path='/products/:id/:subid' component={Products} />
      <Route exact path='/products/:id/:subid/:slug' component={Product} />
```

EDIT:

It works like this:

```
<Link
     to={`/products/${category.id}/${subcategory.id}/${product.slug}`}
     className='products__product-link'
     key={product.id}
>
```

But is it the correct way to do it?

Comment: share some code for understanding problem

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/         Take a look at if you want to see some examples or share code snippets of your project

Comment: I added routes to the original post. What code do you need?